# Why is snap bugging me about Firefox when I already have the latest installed?

Tags: 22.04, firefox, snap

So I regularly see this:

[image]

while accroding to snap itself, I'm already running the latest, which is confirmed by the Firefox's `About` dialog:

[image]

How do I tell snap to shut up?

Running Kubuntu 22.04...

Answer (score 0):

Try to close all instances of Firefox :

```
sudo killall firefox
```

And then refresh snap :

```
sudo snap refresh
```

PS: it's required to close all firefox instances before refresh snap.